# Qt close a running window through code

Tags: c++, qt, window

I have a program that opens another window and i want the old window to close. Is there some function or something that would close the window through the code but keep the other window running?

Comment: Can you just [hide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#hide) (`QWidget` function) it? Or did you mean something else by "close"?

Comment: no i want to make the window go away not the widget inside.

Comment: You can still use hide on window. Application will run as long as it has one visible window.

Comment: Windows *are* widgets, meaning that you can hide the whole thing - not just the contents.

Comment: I type ui->hide() and it tells me that Ui::MainWindow had no member named 'hide'

Comment: @tyty5949 Try `this->hide()` or just `hide()`.

Answer (score 10):

```
this->close();
```

or

```
close();
```

Ref: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#close

Answer (score 2):

```
void Dialog::on_Close_clicked()  // Condition for Main thread program stopping

Running Thread->closethread = true;
    this->close();

void Dialog::on_Stop_clicked()  // Condition For Stop Button for your particular task
{
    this->close();
}
```

Comment: Please add description of what this code block is doing. Else it becomes hard to understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyWidget *newform = new MyWidget;
newform->show();
this->hide();
```

Answer (score -2):

Use signal and slot mechanism.

Whenever you want to close that window or screen emit a signal and connect this signal to the close slot of that window. This should work fine.

Comment: Do I need a computer or a laptop for that?